# How to play video?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, video

I'm not c++ programmer so I have problem. Simple problem, I think.

I need play movie, can be only e.g. .avi (I can convert). Static width, static height, no button, no loop. I will write in PHP something like

```
exec('window.exe movie23.avi');
```

And appears window, play video, window close.

I rely code or good links.

Best regards

Comment: Are you trying to do this in PHP or in C++? I'm confused.

Comment: In c++. I wanna make this window in c++, but open in PHP

Comment: @Piskvor: the OP is asking us to provide the working movie player application, so he's doing neither, I think.

Comment: Check out this page. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd564580(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

So you are a PHP programmer who needs to make a small window ( written in C++ ) that will play a video provided by the command line. Look into the animation control on msdn. It plays avi files. If you are completely inexperienced in the topic , then you have a lot to learn. I would say that you could write something like this in under 200 lines of code.

Best of luck....